# Coming error when I trying to add Font to React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

Still I am learning react native. So I was bulding a simple app with React-Native. So I tried to add Google Font to that App.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Home from './Screens/Home';
import * as Font from 'expo-font'; 
import AppLoading from 'expo';

const getFonts = () => Font.loadAsync({
  'rale': require('./assets/Fonts/Raleway-VariableFont_wght.ttf'),
}); 

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return (<Home />);
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={getFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Code of App.js.

It shows following errors.
[image]

I want to get know what is this error and how to fix that. I am bit new to React-Native.

Comment: Add Curly Braces to your import statement of AppLoading like 'import { AppLoading } from 'expo';' . Try using this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom fonts by following these steps:

1. Keep all .ttf files in 'android/app/src/main/assets/fonts' directory. (I think you have already done that)
2. Create a new file (if doesn't exist) in the root directory with name 'react-native.config.js' and add following lines of code in it -

   module.exports = {
   project: {
   ios: {},
   android: {},
   },
   assets: ['./assets/fonts']
   };
3. Run 'npm react-native link' command from root directory
4. Now you can use fonts in stylesheet or as inline style without adding any other piece of code.